# Conversion from SVG-xml to UIImage in Swift

Tags: swift, url, uiview, uiimage, swiftsvg

Using Swift5 and Xcode-10.2,

How can I get a UIImage from data that is represented in SVG-xml ?

I tried to use SwiftSVG.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftSVG

let ui = UIView(SVGData: data)
ui.frame = self.imgLogo.frame
ui.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.imgLogo.addSubview(ui)
```